# PHP sql query not returning correct number of rows to frontend

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to create a website in which php connects with backend sql. There is 1 row with username = 'user1'.

[image]

However this simple PHP code to fetch the details of 'user1' -

```
<?php
    /* Database credentials. Assuming you are running MySQL
    server with default setting (user 'root' with password 'root') */
    define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
    define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
    define('DB_NAME', 'startup');

    /* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */
    $conn = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

    // Check connection
    if($conn === false){
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    echo '<p>Connected successfully</p>';

    $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql);
    $param_username = "user1";
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    // mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
    echo '<p>done</p>';
    $val = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
    printf("%%d = '%d'\n", $val); // standard integer representation
?>
```

above code is returning this output -

[image]

The value of $val is 0, when clearly there is 1 row with username = 'user1'. Kindly help, I need to get the details of 'user1' in my php script.

Comment: You shouldn't be posting outputs as images. Copy and paste them into your question body instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use connection variable name correctly everywhere.(In yout case it's `$conn`, but you used `$link`)

```
<?php
    /* Database credentials. Assuming you are running MySQL
    server with default setting (user 'root' with password 'root') */
    define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
    define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
    define('DB_NAME', 'startup');

    $conn = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

    /* check connection */
    if (!$conn) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    $param_username = "user1";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE `username` = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

    /* execute prepared statement */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    printf("%d Row inserted.\n", mysqli_num_rows($stmt));

    /* close statement and connection */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

    /* close connection */
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. The error was in the variable name. my sql connect line was `$conn = mysqli_connect(...)`. Wrong variable name.

Answer (score -1):

You did something wrong please update with this and try

```
$sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql);
$param_username = "user1";
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Comment: still doesnt work, same issue. Updating the code in the question.

Comment: try like this https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php